# Javascript/jquery velocity program code does not increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't for the life of me work out why my ball.x does not increment by 0.2 every time my animate function is called? I made one that worked fine that just automatically incremented, but I want this one to increment when you press either left or right. Any ideas??

```
<script>
var canvas;
var context;
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var ball = new Ball();
ball.radius = 15;
var vx = 0;
var ax = 0;
var keyPressed;

$(document).ready(function() {
    canvas = $("#myCanvas");
    context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    canvasWidth = canvas.width();
    canvasHeight = canvas.height();     
    animate();
});

function checkKeys(e) {
    keyPressed = e.keyCode;
    console.log(keyPressed);    
    if(keyPressed == 37)
    {
        ax = -0.2;
    }
    if(keyPressed == 39)
    {
        ax = 0.2;
    }       
}



function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate, canvas);
    draw();
    //console.log(vx);  
};



function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ball.y = canvasHeight / 2;
    ball.x = canvasWidth / 2;
    vx = vx + ax;
    ball.x = ball.x + vx;
    console.log(ball.x);    
    ball.draw(context);                             
}


    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: you have to use += and -= in checkKeys function, not just "="!

Comment: @rikpg No. Quoting BenParsons: This is not relevant because he is using ax to affect vx in the draw function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not calling `checkKeys()` - where are you expecting this to be called from?

Comment: The ball object moves left or right when I press the keys at the moment, it just stays moving at 0.2, so I didn't think I would have to call checkKeys() somewhere else?